# GridSearchCV paramaters

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means, gridsearchcv

I'm trying to use `GridSearchCV` with `KMeans` clustering to explore the optimal number to clusters to use in order to get the best results on a classification problem.

I've got the following code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

faces = fetch_olivetti_faces()

X_data, y_data = faces.data, faces.target
log_reg = LogisticRegression()

split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits = 1, test_size=.2, random_state=42)

for train_index, test_index in split.split(X_train, y_train):
    X_train_set , y_train_set = X_data[train_index,], y_data[train_index,]
    X_test_set, y_test_set = X_data[test_index,], y_data[test_index, ]

pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('kmeans', KMeans(n_clusters = 30)),
        ('log_reg', LogisticRegression())
    ])

cluster_grid = dict(n_clusters=range(2,100))
grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, cluster_grid)

grid.fit(X_train_set, y_train_set, cv=5, verbose=2)
```

Here's the entire traceback:

```
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-80e6a3932897> in <module>
----> 1 grid.fit(X_train_set, y_train_set, cv=5, verbose=2)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    686                 return results
    687 
--> 688             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    689 
    690         # For multi-metric evaluation, store the best_index_, best_params_ and

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1147     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1148         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1149         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1150 
   1151 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    665                                for parameters, (train, test)
    666                                in product(candidate_params,
--> 667                                           cv.split(X, y, groups)))
    668 
    669                 if len(out) < 1:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    919             # remaining jobs.
    920             self._iterating = False
--> 921             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    922                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
    923 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    757                 return False
    758             else:
--> 759                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    760                 return True
    761 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    714         with self._lock:
    715             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 716             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    717             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    718             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    180     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    181         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 182         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    183         if callback:
    184             callback(result)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    547         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    548         # arguments in memory
--> 549         self.results = batch()
    550 
    551     def get(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, return_estimator, error_score)
    501     train_scores = {}
    502     if parameters is not None:
--> 503         estimator.set_params(**parameters)
    504 
    505     start_time = time.time()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in set_params(self, **kwargs)
    162         self
    163         """
--> 164         self._set_params('steps', **kwargs)
    165         return self
    166 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py in _set_params(self, attr, **params)
     48                 self._replace_estimator(attr, name, params.pop(name))
     49         # 3. Step parameters and other initialisation arguments
---> 50         super().set_params(**params)
     51         return self
     52 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in set_params(self, **params)
    222                                  'Check the list of available parameters '
    223                                  'with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.' %
--> 224                                  (key, self))
    225 
    226             if delim:

ValueError: Invalid parameter n_clusters for estimator Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('kmeans',
                 KMeans(algorithm='auto', copy_x=True, init='k-means++',
                        max_iter=300, n_clusters=30, n_init=10, n_jobs=None,
                        precompute_distances='auto', random_state=None,
                        tol=0.0001, verbose=0)),
                ('log_reg',
                 LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False,
                                    fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1,
                                    l1_ratio=None, max_iter=100,
                                    multi_class='warn', n_jobs=None,
                                    penalty='l2', random_state=None,
                                    solver='warn', tol=0.0001, verbose=0,
                                    warm_start=False))],
         verbose=False). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

​

I have no idea what the heck is going on...I'm not sure how to interpret this error message but my parameter grid doesn't seem to be out of wack.  PLEASE HELP!

Comment: can you scroll down and show the entire traceback

Comment: I edited to original post to show the traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `pipeline` you need to give the parameters as following:

```
cluster_grid = {
    'kmeans__n_clusters': range(2,100)
}
# adding n_jobs to run in parallel
grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, cluster_grid, n_jobs=-1)
```

where `kmeans` is taken from `('kmeans', KMeans())`

So, your code should look as the following:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('kmeans', KMeans(),
    ('log_reg', LogisticRegression())
])
cluster_grid = {
    'kmeans__n_clusters': range(2,100)
}
# adding n_jobs to run in parallel
grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, cluster_grid, n_jobs=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `n_clusters` is only applicable to `KMeans` and not `LogisticRegression`

Specify in your cluster_grid that the grid param is only meant for `KMeans`:

```
# Parameters of pipelines can be set using ‘__’ separated parameter names:

cluster_grid = dict(kmeans__n_clusters=range(2,100))
```

Reference : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/putting_together.html